# Yii2: Labels with attributeLabels() in GridView

Tags: model-view-controller, gridview, yii2

I generated a model which got the function `attributeLabels()`:

```
public function attributeLabels()
{
    return [
        'column1' => 'name of column1',
        'column2' => 'name of column2',
    ];
}
```

I also wrote a function in my model, which creates a SQL statement:

```
public function getReminders()
{
        $sql = Yii::$app->db->createCommand('SELECT 
        [[column1]], [[column2]]
        FROM {{%table}}
        WHERE column1 > :value')
        -> bindValue(':value', '10');
        return $sql;
}
```

Then I created a controller with an `actionIndex()` function:

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $model = new TestObject();
    $testmodels= new ActiveDataProvider([
      'models' => $model->getReminders()->queryAll(),

    ]);

    return $this->render('index', [
        'testmodels' => $testmodels,
    ]);
```

Finally I created a View

```
GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $testmodels,
        'layout' => '{items}{pager}',
        'columns' => ['column1', column2,],
    ]);
```

For some reason, the column names of the resulting page are `column1` and `column2`. I have tried to create a listView and got the correct names for the columns. How comes that the column names are not set by `attributeLabels()` in this case? I really don't want to use the `label` property in the gridview.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: That is because you are not getting any benefit from your model at all. First, `queryAll` which you are calling returns array of arrays not array of models. Second, There is no need to instantiate `$model = new TestObject()`, You can make `getReminders` static and move it completely from `TestObject`

Comment: What is the base class for your model? is it ActiveRecord or just a Model?

Comment: dude what are you trying to to do. can you explain in easy words.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to change the label for the gridview column you can configure you column with proper value for  label

```
GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $testmodels,
        'layout' => '{items}{pager}',
        'columns' => [
          [
            'attribute'=> column1',
            'label' => 'Your Lable for column 1',
          ],
          [
            'attribute'=> column2',
            'label' => 'Your Lable for column 2',
          ],
        ],
    ]);
```

you can take a look at thsi for a brief guide http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-output-data-widgets.html  or here for ref http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-grid-datacolumn.html

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following:

1. make the base class for the TestObject be ActiveRecord
2. Override `tableName`
3. Simplify getReminders, make it static, and let it return `Query` not a `Command`

   class TestModel extends yii\db\ActiveRecord
   {
       ...

   ```
   public static function tableName()
   {
       return {{%table}};
   }

   public static function getReminders()
   {
       $query = self::find()->select(['column1', 'column2'])
           ->where(['>', 'column1', 10]);
       return $query;
   }    

   ...
   ```

   }
4. Don't set `models` of the `ActiveDataProvier` and instead set `query`

   'models' => TestObject::getReminders(),